# Route53 custom domain not updating content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I am using a S3 bucket to serve a static site. I updated my bucket with new deployment. The S3 bucket domain name is serving the correct content and updating accordingly.

I am using Amazon CloudFront to manage my custom domain (via route53) & my SSL cert(via AWS cert manager)

I have set up an invalidation on cloudfront for all content ( i.e '/*') which is working correctly. For example the cloudfront distribution domain name is serving the correct content and updating accordingly.

However, the custom domain name (Alternate domain name (CNAME)) is not updating when S3 and CloudFront are??

Is my custom domain also caching somewhere, and I need to make changes to the configuration?

Thanks